# React native build signed apk ( after eject expo ) Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

first of all I'm so tired with this error I've trying for 4 days to solve this error , I'm stress right now I still can build this project to apk the commandline say this :

[image]

i've tried everything :(

Comment: Did you run the more verbose options suggested, such as info or debug?